# Communication between one parent to 4 child processes

Tags: c, pipe

I am quite new to C and currently trying to implement a program that will prompt a user input(integer) in the parent process. Then the parent process will send the integer to 4 child process. In each child process, it perform addition with its index + 1 (i + 1 in the outer for-loop) and the integer sent from the parent process. After that, each process will send the modifies number back to the parent process.

Currently, I have created in total 5 processes(including the main process) and 5 pipes. The current issue of the program is that the it hangs after it finishes sending all 4 modified integer back to the parent

For example: if the input is 1
Child 0 should send 1 + (0 + 1) = 2 back to parent process
Child 1 should send 1 + (1 + 1) = 3 back to parent process
and so on...

I am not sure what is wrong. I was wondering maybe I did not close the correct pipes. Pls help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int pipes[5][2], pid[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (pipe(pipes[i]) == -1) {
            printf("Error in piping");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == -1) {
            printf("Error in forking");
        }
        if (pid[i] == 0) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                if (j > 0 && j != i) {
                    close(pipes[j][0]);
                }
            }
            int x;
            read(pipes[i][0], &x, sizeof(int));
            printf("Child %d received %d from parents\n", i + 1, x);
            x += (i + 1);
            write(pipes[0][1], &x, sizeof(int));
            printf("Child %d sent %d to parent\n", i + 1, x);
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            return 0;
        } 
    }

    printf("Input a number: ");
    int y, z;
    scanf("%d", &y);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        write(pipes[j][1], &y, sizeof(int));
        printf("Writing %d to child %d\n", y, j + 1);
    }
    
    while (read(pipes[0][0], &z, sizeof(int)) > 0) {
        printf("Received %d\n", z);
    }

    close(pipes[0][0]);
    close(pipes[0][1]);

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should report errors on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  You should terminate error messages with a newline.  You should stop the program (`exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`) after reporting an error such as 'failed to create a pipe'.  None of which directly addresses your problem, but you need to develop good habits now, while learning.

Comment: Check the return value of all the `read` and `close` calls.  It seem odd to have `if (j > 0 && j != i) {`; why not close the read pipe when j == 0?

Comment: I think your indexing is off.  If you are keeping the j==0 pipe open, then you probably want to use i+1 for the child pipe, instead of i

Comment: It seems that `pipes[0]` is supposed to be reserved for communication from the children back to the parent, but the first child (i == 0) is reading from that pipe.   That's not what causes the block, though.  Your parent doesn't close `pipes[0][1]` until *after* it  reads from `pipes[0][0]`, so it is blocked on a read.  Classic deadlock; the parent is trying to read from the pipe while it still has the write side of the pipe open.

Comment: What if I want to prompt input until the user enters -1. Then, I will need an infinite loop at the main process and child process. Where do I close my pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children write to the parent on `pipe[0][1]`; your loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    write(pipes[j][1], &y, sizeof(int));
    printf("Writing %d to child %d\n", y, j + 1);
}
```

writes to pipes 0, 1, 2, and 3 instead of pipes 1, 2, 3, and 4 — so the last child never gets any data to process.  And hence the parent doesn't get EOF on the pipe and hangs.

Additionally, the parent must close the write end of `pipe[0]` before it enters the read loop; otherwise, the loop will jam because the parent could still write to the pipe, even though it is stuck reading from it.

One key part of the fix:

```
for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
{
    write(pipes[j][1], &y, sizeof(int));
    printf("Writing %d to child %d\n", y, j);
}
```

and the parent must close the write end of `pipe[0]` before it loops reading on it to prevent it hanging — in theory, the parent could still write to the pipe even though it is reading from it:

```
close(pipes[0][1]);
while (read(pipes[0][0], &z, sizeof(int)) > 0) {
    printf("Received %d\n", z);
}
```

Here is a cleaned-up version of your code, with other issues addressed.  In particular, the parent closes the read end of the pipes to the children before even writing to the children, and it closes the write end of the pipes to the children once it has finished writing.  This ensures that the parent doesn't have pipe descriptors open that it is not going to use.

```
/* SO 7584-8457 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pipes[5][2], pid[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(pipes[i]) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (pid[i] == 0)
        {
            /* Close the read end of every pipe except the one to this child */
            /* Close the write end of every pipe except the one to the parent */
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                if (j != i + 1)
                    close(pipes[j][0]);
                if (j != 0)
                    close(pipes[j][1]);
            }
            int x;
            read(pipes[i+1][0], &x, sizeof(int));
            printf("Child %d received %d from parents\n", i + 1, x);
            x += (i + 1);
            write(pipes[0][1], &x, sizeof(int));
            printf("Child %d sent %d to parent\n", i + 1, x);
            close(pipes[i + 1][0]);
            close(pipes[0][1]);
            exit(x);
        }
    }

    printf("Input a number: ");
    int y;
    scanf("%d", &y);
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        close(pipes[j][0]);
        write(pipes[j][1], &y, sizeof(int));
        printf("Writing %d to child %d\n", y, j);
        close(pipes[j][1]);
    }

    int z;
    close(pipes[0][1]);
    while (read(pipes[0][0], &z, sizeof(int)) > 0)
        printf("Received %d\n", z);
    close(pipes[0][0]);

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);

    return 0;
}
```

One example run gave me the output:

```
Input a number: 14
Writing 14 to child 1
Writing 14 to child 2
Writing 14 to child 3
Writing 14 to child 4
Child 1 received 14 from parent
Child 1 sent 15 to parent
Child 4 received 14 from parent
Child 4 sent 18 to parent
Received 15
Child 3 received 14 from parent
Received 18
Child 3 sent 17 to parent
Received 17
Child 2 received 14 from parent
Child 2 sent 16 to parent
Received 16
Child 63545 exited with status 0x1200
Child 63544 exited with status 0x1100
Child 63543 exited with status 0x1000
Child 63542 exited with status 0x0F00
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
while (read(pipes[0][0], &z, sizeof(int)) > 0) {
        printf("Received %d\n", z);
}

close(pipes[0][0]);
close(pipes[0][1]);
```

This is a classic deadlock.  Before the loop, the parent has `pipes[0][1]` open.  The `read(pipes[0][0],...)` will block until the parent closes `pipes[0][1]`, but since that does not happen until after the loop, the `read` is blocked indefinitely.  Move the `close(pipes[0][1])` so that it happens before the while loop.